# Exclude one program in data usage

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring

My provider provides rdio for free. This generates data traffic, but is not taken from my data plan. How can I exclude this program from data usage limit and or calculation?

Comment: Maybe some external app can do it.

Comment: could you be more specific?